# graph traveling algorithm to recursively find max value

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, datomic

I have a sparse directed graph. The graph is tree-ish but may have cycles, it is not very deep and the whole graph always fits in ram. Each node in the graph has an integer value.

For a starting node, how can I find the largest reachable value:

1. for the starting node, and
2. for all reachable nodes (which are already visited to determine #1)

(Not homework. I have a datomic entity graph and I want to recursively determine the last-modified-tx for each node reachable from a starting point.)

Comment: For a given starting vertex, ordinary DFS or BFS (including marking already-visited vertices) will do this in O(|V|+|E|) time, which is optimal.  DFS will use less memory if the graph resembles a shallow tree.  For (2), are you asking to repeat (1) for each vertex, treating it as the starting vertex?  You can do the same as before, though this will take quadratic time.  A faster way involves finding all Strongly Connected Components.

Comment: why will #2 take quadratic time? all nodes are visited in the same time as #1

Comment: Suppose all vertices are initially white, and we colour a vertex grey when DFS enters it and black when we leave it.  Let's maintain the invariant that the stored value for all black vertices is final and accurate.  We process white children by recursing into them, which eventually turns them black.  If after doing that we only have black children, we can simply take the maximum of all of their values and our own value, and assign that to ourselves.  The difficulty is: how to handle a grey child (which happens when there is a cycle) and stay within O(|V|+|E|) time? ...

Comment: ...   An "ordinary" DFS would ignore grey children completely -- this will result in an accurate value for the root, but possibly inaccurate values for all other vertices that participate in a cycle.  So you would need to rerun it for every vertex, with that vertex as the root.  (Alternatively, if you can think of a way to handle grey children efficiently, then you don't need to do this.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using the pull API's [recursive specifications](http://docs.datomic.com/pull.html#recursive-specifications)?

The doc example is fairly straight forward and would work for the case you describe (with appropriate attributes for your domain):

```
[:person/firstName :person/lastName {:person/friends ...}]
```

given that the entire graph fits in memory (the main gotcha with this approach). Recursion in pull is tolerant of cycles and won't apply the pull pattern to a previously visited entity. This could be adapted to be, e.g.:

```
[:node/value {:node/next ...}]
```